# How to look up a local IP address and save it to a text file

Tags: c#

I made a program which looks up someone's local IP address and saves the output as a text file. But I can't call the `static void IP()` method, because it needs the the `string[] args` parameter and I don't know how to get this. Where can I obtain the array I need to pass to the method?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IPObtainer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("E:\\ip.txt"))
            {
                Console.SetOut(writer);
                IP();
            }
        }

        static void IP(string[] args)
        {
            String StringHost;
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                // Getting IP of local machine...
                // First get the host name of the local machine...
                StringHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
                Console.WriteLine("Local machine host name is: " + StringHost);
                Console.WriteLine("");

            }
            else
            {
                StringHost = args[0];
            }


            // The using hostname, get the IP address List...
            IPHostEntry ipEntry =
                System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(StringHost);

            IPAddress[] address = ipEntry.AddressList;

            for (int i = 0; i < address.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("IP Address Type {0}: {1} ", i, address[i].ToString());
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *but it dont work* what does that mean BTW? what doesn't work in specific?

Comment: You never call any of your code in `Main`.

Comment: It's considered polite to add text or a #tag that tells your audience that you're coding in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the code you've correctly, you mean to allow the program to be run from the command line, with a machine name provided as an optional command line argument.

Here is a version of your code that should work:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("E:\\ip.txt"))
        {
            IP(args, writer);
        }
    }

    static void IP(string[] args, TextWriter writer)
    {
        String StringHost;
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            // Getting IP of local machine...
            // First get the host name of the local machine...
            StringHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            writer.WriteLine("Local machine host name is: " + StringHost);
            writer.WriteLine("");

        }
        else
        {
            StringHost = args[0];
        }

        // The using hostname, get the IP address List...
        IPHostEntry ipEntry =
            System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(StringHost);

        IPAddress[] address = ipEntry.AddressList;

        for (int i = 0; i < address.Length; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("");
            writer.WriteLine("IP Address Type {0}: {1} ", i, address[i].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

- The `Main()` method is given a `string[] args` parameter, which will be passed by the runtime, and will contain the command line arguments. This is then passed to your `IP()` method
- It is a *really* bad idea to co-opt the `Console` output streams for writing to a file. Instead, note in the above how I pass the writer object to the `IP()` method and let it us that directly, instead of being tied to the `Console` class.

Comment: Thank you you're a live saver.

Comment: And ty for your tips

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, there is no need to change it.   The main method can take a string[] as a parameter, then you just pass it along to the IP static function.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IPObtainer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("E:\\ip.txt"))
            {
                Console.SetOut(writer);
                 IP(args);
            }
        }

        static void IP(string[] args)
        {
            String StringHost;
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                // Getting IP of local machine...
                // First get the host name of the local machine...
                StringHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
                Console.WriteLine("Local machine host name is: " + StringHost);
                Console.WriteLine("");

            }
            else
            {
                StringHost = args[0];
            }


            // The using hostname, get the IP address List...
            IPHostEntry ipEntry =
                System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(StringHost);

            IPAddress[] address = ipEntry.AddressList;

            for (int i = 0; i < address.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("IP Address Type {0}: {1} ", i, address[i].ToString());
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And I see peter beat me to it.